# My node is rendering another view ejs but the path is correct

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, view, ejs

My route is use render for a view in ejs, the path is corret but the view in the route is a old view i'm used for test.

My server.js:

[image: server.js]

My route:

[image: the route]

My files structure:

[image]

I want the view cadastroAtividade.ejs but shows admAtividades.ejs

I don't know how fix. Any help is welcome.

Comment: what if you kill the process and start the server again?

Comment: yes, I also thought about it, I did it about 2 times and even then it shows the old view

Comment: tried clearing browsers' cache?

Comment: I also tried, hahaha. I'm desperate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the file ejs, there was an if...else it was conditioned to the button of the page that was with problematic view. After removing this conditional the view stopped giving error.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to set up all the directories with the views, just do the following :

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

In your route, in my case, this is in `routes\contact\about-us.js` i have the following code :

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
return res.render('pages/contact/about-us');
});
```

In my case i have the directory structure  `views\pages\contact\about-us.ejs`

I have this in the `app.js` :

```
const contactUs = require('./routes/contact/contact-us');
app.use('/contact-us', contactUs);
```

Sorry i couldn't use your directories for the example since they are images, it would be easy if you pasted text.

Comment: Yes, i set up the directories this way in the first time and works, but when I created the sub folders he did not recognize them. I tried again now and i got the error:  "path is not defined"

Comment: To the top of the file add `const path = require("path")`

Comment: I did this, did not give the path error, but I got this new error in the problematic route: Error: Failed to lookup view "atividades/admAtividades" in views directory "C:\Users\Raquel\Desktop\monitoriaUflaApi\views"

Comment: Then probably your views folder isn't exactly "C:\Users\Raquel\Desktop\monitoriaUflaApi\views"

Comment: At least with that mistake I discovered that he is really reading the wrong path for ejs. Internally, of course, because in my code it's right

Comment: But the folder is there, haha.